# My app won't run on the emulator (android studio)

Tags: android

I have loaded my app on the emulator and it comes up with the phone but it won't load the app. When I click on the android monitor it says there is no connected devices and nothing is in the logcat.
I have run it before and it was working fine but now I'm trying and it won't work.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Drivers of the device are correctly installed? Did you enable the developer options in the device?

Comment: your question are much vague

Comment: It'd help if you would be more specific. What emulator are you using (default, genymotion)? What IDE you're on? And if possible, provide screenshots of the emulator. Also, this phrase is very confusing -- *I have loaded my app on the emulator and it comes up with the phone but it won't load the app.*